# Lets encrypt SSL in Ubuntu 16 apache server returns 404 error

Tags: apache, ssl, laravel-5, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt

I have a digitalocean droplet where I have hosted a Laravel application [App Url](http://assamgas.tk) . I have added a SSL using [Tutorial Link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04). But when I run the application in `https` it returns `404` page not found error. can anyone check the issue. Config file ( assamgas.tk.conf ) is below.
[image: assamgas.tk.conf]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing two things wrong here.

1) The web server is not redirecting to port 443 (SSL/HTTPS)
2) The certificate is not present.

I could not find any certs through HTTPS on your server.

I suggest, run through the tutorial again, or try this  [DigitalOcean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Don't generate too many production certificates while you test, rather use the Let's Encrypt staging server for your testing, when you get the self-signed certificate, then you switch over to the production server for Let's Encrypt, otherwise you will get [Rate Limited](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/) for a week.